# While loop hangs and does not find string

Tags: bash

I have a section of code in a bash script that uses a while loop to grep a file until the string I am looking for is there, then exit. Currently, its just hanging using the following code:

```
hostname="test-cust-15"
VAR1=$(/bin/grep -wo -m1 "HOST ALERT: $hostname;DOWN"  /var/log/logfile)

while [ ! "$VAR1" ]
do
sleep 5
done
echo $VAR1 was found
```

I know the part of the script responsible for inserting this string into the logfile works, as I can grep it out side of the script and find it.

One thing I have tried is to change up the variables. Like this:

```
hostname="test-cust-15"
VAR1="HOST ALERT: $hostname;DOWN"


while [ ! /bin/grep "$VAR1" /var/log/logfile ]
do
sleep 5
done
echo $VAR1 was found
```

But i get a binary operator expected message and once I got a too many arguments message when using this:

```
while [ ! /bin/grep -q -wo "$VAR1" /var/log/logfile ]
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: `while [ ! $(/bin/grep -wo -m1 "HOST ALERT: $hostname;DOWN"  /var/log/logfile) ]` should do it.

Comment: Did you try: `while [ ! "$(/bin/grep "$VAR1" /var/log/logfile)" ]` ? @ElliottFrisch only seconds faster :-)

Comment: Will give these a try

Comment: It seems to be better and the while loop echo's out the string so I know its finding it. But now I am getting the erro [: ALERT:: binary operator expected and it refers to the while loop line.

Comment: Or even shorter: `until /bin/grep "$VAR1" /var/log/logfile`

Comment: enclosing the while loop in double brackets resolved the binary operator expected error.

Answer (score 3):

`while`/`until` can work off of the exit status of a program directly.

```
until /bin/grep "$VAR1" /var/log/logfile
do
    sleep 5
done
echo "$VAR1" was found
```

You also mentioned that it prints out the match in an above comment. If that's *not* desirable, use output redirection, or grep's -q option.

```
until /bin/grep "$VAR1" /var/log/logfile >/dev/null

until /bin/grep -q "$VAR1" /var/log/logfile
```

Comment: Even better, use the `-q` option with `grep` to suppress output at the source.

Answer (score 2):

No need to bother with command substitution or test operator there. Simply:

```
while ! grep -wo -m1 "HOST ALERT: $hostname;DOWN"  /var/log/logfile; do
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste resources, use tail!

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
    do
    echo $line
    break
done < <(tail -f /tmp/logfile | grep --line-buffered "HOST ALERT")
```